# Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit,reason="execution reverted"

Tags: hardhat, chainlink-vrf

```
$ yarn hardhat run scripts/mockOffChain.js --network goerli
yarn run v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
$ '/home/rajvir_singh/FCC Full stack Web3 course/Hardhat Lottery L9/node_modules/.bin/hardhat' run scripts/mockOffChain.js --network goerli
1:[object Object]
3
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x173537ED978c9EAdE509DeA2DeEf114f04F25490","to":"0x4E7914084d7936B07d9B8AFfD588d5469A401958","data":"0x4585e33b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020c5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470","accessList":null}, error={"name":"ProviderError","_stack":"ProviderError: execution reverted\n    at HttpProvider.request (/home/rajvir_singh/FCC Full stack Web3 course/Hardhat Lottery L9/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:88:21)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/home/rajvir_singh/FCC Full stack Web3 course/Hardhat Lottery L9/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)","code":3,"_isProviderError":true,"data":"0xa73869760000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c8"}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (/home/rajvir_singh/FCC Full stack Web3 course/Hardhat Lottery L9/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (/home/rajvir_singh/FCC Full stack Web3 course/Hardhat Lottery L9/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
    at checkError (/home/rajvir_singh/FCC Full stack Web3 course/Hardhat Lottery L9/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/json-rpc-provider.ts:78:20)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.<anonymous> (/home/rajvir_singh/FCC Full stack Web3 course/Hardhat Lottery L9/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/json-rpc-provider.ts:642:20)
    at step (/home/rajvir_singh/FCC Full stack Web3 course/Hardhat Lottery L9/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (/home/rajvir_singh/FCC Full stack Web3 course/Hardhat Lottery L9/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (/home/rajvir_singh/FCC Full stack Web3 course/Hardhat Lottery L9/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'execution reverted',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
  method: 'estimateGas',
  transaction: {
    from: '0x173537ED978c9EAdE509DeA2DeEf114f04F25490',
    to: '0x4E7914084d7936B07d9B8AFfD588d5469A401958',
    data: '0x4585e33b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020c5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470',
    accessList: null
  },
  error: ProviderError: execution reverted
      at HttpProvider.request (/home/rajvir_singh/FCC Full stack Web3 course/Hardhat Lottery L9/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:88:21)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/home/rajvir_singh/FCC Full stack Web3 course/Hardhat Lottery L9/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

mockOffChain.js

```
const { ethers, network } = require("hardhat")

async function mockKeepers() {
    // const raffle = await ethers.getContractAt("Raffle")
    const contractAddress = (await deployments.get("Raffle")).address
    const raffle_contract = await ethers.getContractAt("Raffle", contractAddress)
    const raffle = raffle_contract
    //await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(subscriptionId, raffle.address)
    const checkData = ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(""))
    const { upkeepNeeded } = await raffle.callStatic.checkUpkeep(checkData)
    //console.log(`1:${{ upkeepNeeded }}`)
    if (upkeepNeeded) {
        //console.log("3")
        const tx = await raffle.performUpkeep(checkData)
        //console.log(`2:${{ tx }}`)
        const txReceipt = await tx.wait(1)
        const requestId = txReceipt.events[1].args.requestId
        console.log(`Performed upkeep with RequestId: ${requestId}`)
        if (network.config.chainId == 31337) {
            await mockVrf(requestId, raffle)
        }
    } else {
        console.log("No upkeep needed!")
    }
}

async function mockVrf(requestId, raffle) {
    console.log("We on a local network? Ok let's pretend...")
    const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
    await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(requestId, raffle.address)
    console.log("Responded!")
    const recentWinner = await raffle.getRecentWinner()
    console.log(`The winner is: ${recentWinner}`)
}

mockKeepers()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
        process.exit(1)
    })
```

I am using chainlink VRF and I have correctly added the consumer address(goerli contract address) but when I run the script it gives me this error and if run `yarn hardhat run scripts/mockOffChain.js` then also I get the same error. Please help me resolve this error